# valid JSON equivalent of the key/value pair also preserves the data type

Tags: javascript, json, types

I got a question in online exam .. but i can not find any solution . there is multiple choice option..

Question : which code is valid JSON equivalent of the key/value pair show that also preserves the data type ?

1  :  `"constant" : "6.022E23"`

2 :  `"constant" : "6\.022\E23"`

3 :  `"constant" : 6.022E23`

Comment: should be option 3

Comment: why  @Kunal Mukherjee ? plz  explain ...

Comment: parsing this doesn't throw an exception - ``JSON.parse(`{"constant" : 6.022E23}`)``

Comment: options 1 and 2 also parsing  doesn't throw an exception @KunalMukherjee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has two condition one **Valid JSON** another is **Preserves Value**.  **Option 1 and 2** valid json but not preserve value. I consider preserve value as a **float number** ( 6.022E23 ). I figure it out that only **Option 3** full fill both conditions : **Valid JSON and Preserve Value** . I think **Option 3** will be right answer.

**Note:**  If anyone has better explanation please Explain ...